# Error Message: cannot bind to the property or column on the datasource. parameter name datamember c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, label, bindingsource

I have a C# Windows Forms App which I edit using VS 2013. Data has been retrieved from an SQL database and stored in a DataTable called `Properties` within a DataSet (`ds`). No error when I fill the text field of a Label using:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ds.Tables["Properties"], "myColumn", true));
```

But, I get the error message if I use a BindingSource as the DataSource instead of the DataSet DataTable:

Autogenerated code in the Designer file (BindingSource added to form from Toolbox):

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsProperties;
this.bsProperties = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
```

In the code file:

```
bsProperties.DataSource = ds.Tables["Properties"];
label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bsProperties, "myColumn", true));
```

Why do I get this error message when I try to access the same DataTable within the DataSet? Is the call to `DataBindings.Add()` different if I use a BindingSource as the DataSource instead of a DataSet DataTable as the DataSource?

My ultimate goal is to use the BindingSource to fill a ComboBox and then the Label is filled with data that pertains to the selected item in the ComboBox (stored in the same row in the DataSet as the data in the ComboBox). For this I think I will need to use DataRowView but that is a question for another day.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Something must be different with your DataSet or DataTable.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech . I forgot to mention the app is 3-tier architecture. The DataSet schema was created in the BLL. The DataTables in the DataSet were created using the same stored procedure call as that used in the code. The DataSet in the Presentation Layer is then of the BLL.DataSet type. I make a call to BLL which calls DAL which uses stored procedure to access database. Does this matter do you think? I wouldn't think it would given that I can get data out one way but not the other.

Comment: That's a lot of details, so maybe it's a case of getting lost in your own museum.  But try testing your binding source: `((DataTable)bsProperties.DataSource).Rows[0]["myColumn"].ToString()` and see what you get.

Comment: I tested the binding source. I got out the data I expected. The issue is when I try to look at the next record.

Comment: `The issue is when I try to look at the next record.`  Your question doesn't contain any information about a *next record.*.  It just says one binding method works, the other doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I make the call to the database to get a list that is stored in ds.Table[0]. This list is shown in a UltraWinGrid on the Form. When I select a row in the grid, another call to the database is made using a value from the selected row for further details about that item. These details are stored in ds.Table[1] or ds.Tables["Properties"], which is then displayed in the ComboBox and Labels. When I move to the next selection in the grid, I get the error message if I use the BindingSource as the DataSource. No error message if I use the DataSet as the DataSource.